# Pull random comment from specific post, display on homepage with shortcode

Tags: functions, shortcode

I'm trying to display a random comment from specific posts on my homepage, using the solution that was provided here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790239/random-comments-on-page-wordpress/11790460#11790460

It works, but it pulls a random comment from a random post, instead of selecting the post I point at with the shortcode. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
add_shortcode( 'randomComment', 'randomComment_handler' );

function randomComment_handler($post_id) {
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'post_id' => '0',
    ), $atts ) );
$out = "";
$comments = get_comments("post_id=$post_id&status=approve");
if ($comments) {
    $ndx = mt_rand(0,sizeof($comments)) - 1; 
    $comment = $comments[$ndx];
    $out = "<div class='randomComment'><div class='randomAuthor'>".$comment->comment_author."</div><div class='randomText'>".$comment->comment_content."</div></div>";
}
return $out;
}
```

and the shortcode:

```
[randomComment post_id="463"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with the code snippet is this line:

```
function randomComment_handler($post_id) {
```

Check out the Codex on [`add_shortcode()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) and see if you can find the error.

**Spoiler**: It should be like this:

> function randomComment_handler( $atts, $content = NULL ) {

*ps*: You should also avoid using `extract()`, use `$atts['post_id']` instead.

Further  consider adding the third parameter to the [`shortcode_atts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_atts) function.

Comment: excellent, thanks for this solution, works like a charm! can check on memstories.com frontpage

Comment: sorry for the late response, but where do I mark as accepted? [edit: found it.. :)]